# Data showing null in mvc controller when passed through view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, asp.net-ajax, kendo-grid

I'm new to MVC and using kendo ui grid in my project. I've come up with a issue that I'm getting "null" in controller parameter, although data is passing through view. Please see the below code.

Here is my code part from View

```
@model IEnumerable<WeBOC.Support.Entities.Vessel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Vessels";
}

<h2>Vessels</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
.Columns(column =>
    {
        column.Bound(c => c.VIRNbr).Width(100).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=VIRNbr#", "VesselInspector", new { id = "#=VesselVisitId#" }).ToHtmlString()).Title("VIR No.").Width(150);
        column.Bound(c => c.VesselName).Width(150).Title("Vessel Name");
        column.Bound(c => c.InboundVoyageNbr).Width(70).Title("IB Vyg");
        column.Bound(c => c.OutboundVoyageNbr).Width(70).Title("OB Vyg");
        column.Bound(c => c.ETA).Width(100).Title("ETA").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");
        column.Bound(c => c.ArrivalDate).Width(100).Title("ATA").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("Vessels_Read", "VesselVisit", new { id = "\\#=State\\#"})
            ))
)
```

And this is controller method

```
public ActionResult Vessels_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string id)
    {
        return Json(GetVessels(id).ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Why I'm getting null in parameter id although passed through view.

```
public ActionResult Vessels(string id)
    {
        return View(GetVessels(id));
    }

    public IEnumerable<Vessel> GetVessels(string phase)
    {
        IEnumerable<Vessel> vsl = null;
        vsl = this._repository.GetVesselByPhase(phase);            
        return vsl;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ovais

Comment: `State` is a member of `Vessel`? Add a breakpoint on `vsl = this._repository.GetVesselByPhase(phase);` and check if that value is being read from the repository on the first access to your View.

Comment: Yes, State is a member of Vessel. I've already check the value by putting breakpoint. On first access, i'm getting the correct value, but at the time of paging the grid, i'm getting null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass additional parameters to your action you should do something like this:

```
.DataSource( dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read( "Vessels_Read", "VesselVisit" ).Data("getState") //getState is a javascript function
)
```

Then add a script block:

```
<script>
function getState() {
    return {
        ID: // your ID, obtained with jQuery, from the View Model, hardcoded, etc...
    };
}
</script>
```

More info [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-the-action-method).

**EDIT**

I have this working right now. I'm working with a View Model but it shouldn't be any different.

View:

```
.DataSource( dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read( "MY_ACTION", "MY_CONTROLLER", new { Id = Model.Id } )
)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MY_ACTION( [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, long Id )
```

Even if I change `new { Id = Model.Id }` to `new { Id = "QWERTY" }` and the action parameter to string, I receive `"QUERTY"` as the value.

Comment: `.Read(read => read
                .Action("Vessels_Read", "VesselVisit")
                .Data("getvessels")
                )`

Comment: `<script>
    function getvessels() {
        return
        {
            id: $("#State").val
        };
    }
</script>
`

Comment: @user2542561 what's the value of `#=State#` ? where do you get it's value?

Comment: It is of type string, its value is "CLOSED". I've also tried hard coded string "CLOSED" in javascript function, but of no use.. :(

Comment: Do i have to write Route Values??

Comment: @user2542561 On your javascript function, `return { id: $("#State").val };` **val** should be `return { id: $("#State").val() };`. Anyway, check my edited answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Your edited answer works well, but my model is of type IEnumerable and I cannot access properties of Model, i.e. Model.Id, etc. As I'm using kendo grid and wants the value of the field "State". I've also tried `<script>
    function getstate() {
        return
        {
            phase: $("#State").val()
        };
    }
</script>` but still getting null in controller parameter.

Comment: Also tried `.Read(read => read
            .Action("Vessels_Read", "VesselVisit", new { phase = "#=State#"})`, but getting null. Interesting point is that I'm getting correct value of VesselVisitId in this code `column.Bound(c => c.VIRNbr).Width(100).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=VIRNbr#", "VesselInspector", new { id = "#=VesselVisitId#" }).ToHtmlString()).Title("VIR No.").Width(150);`

Comment: Further I've observed that this behavior is for only `ServerOperation(True)`.. When I use False, it works fine.

Comment: @user2542561 I'm getting out of ideas... Try this `.Action("Vessels_Read", "VesselVisit", new { id = "\\#=State#\\"})` on your `Read` action (escaping the State parameter) http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/detail-template-parameters-not-recognizing-template-grid-model-properties-.aspx

Comment: Getting only "\\" in parameter.. :(

Comment: @user2542561 Please edit your question and add the entire Grid code plus the element that has the State value.

Comment: I've edited my question, please see the explanation again on the top.